# Как сделать две разные сборки программ по флагу?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня есть Java проект в IntelliJ IDEA. Мне нужно добавить два разных флага для сборки, чтоб создавая jar файл с одним флагам был доступен весь функционал, а с другим только его часть. Как это осуществить? 
Сейчас я не использую в проекте Gradle/Maven обязательны ли они для этого?

Comment: а конфигом такое не решить? или двумя точками входа (две разные main функции)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал @tym32167 это решилось с помощью двух различных классов Main, и сборки назначая запускаемым необходимым.